# getting my db table into html table gets no results

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

this is my first post and im already totally confused about my project right now :x

im able to make a successful connection to the sql db and also receive my data which displays on the top left, BUT its supposed to display in a html table, not somewhere on the screen :O

Here is the website to see the code in action, though there is none yet!
http://blackskill.square7.ch/

Here is the code which is running fine, but maybe im just too stupid and new for coding yet xd

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php

$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");

if ($connection) {
    echo "database online <br>";
} else {
    die("Connection failed. Reason: ".mysqli_connection_error());
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM blackskill_playerdb";
$results=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($results)>0) {

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

        echo   '<tr>
                <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[2].'</td>
                <td>'.$row[3].'</td>
                </tr>';

        echo "<br>";

    }

}

mysqli_close($connection);

?>


<html>
<head>
    <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 20%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    #myTable th, #myTable td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 12px;
    }

    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    #myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h2><center>Inofficial S.K.I.L.L. - Special Force 2 - Dishonor List</center></h2>

    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="aa" placeholder="Search for player..." title="Type in a name">

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr class="header">
        <th style="width:40%;">Player</th>
        <th style="width:20%;">Clan</th>
        <th style="width:20%;">Evidence</th>
        <th style="width:20%;">Added to list</th>

            <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['clan']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['rulebreak']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['addlist']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile ?>

      </tr>
    </table>
    <tbody>

</body>
</html>
```

i hope we can find an answer together with friendship, emotions and friendship!

regards

Comment: Your already iterated the entire query outside of the HTML body in your first while loop, so there is no data to go through in your second while loop. Remove the first while loop and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! srsly i had to delete 1 single sentence to have such a great impact!!!!!!!! xd Thats one of the reasons why i start to love coding :D

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` return numeric index (`row[0]`) and you are using name index in your table. Change it to `row[0]` or use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: somehow my html search function isnt working (anymore? - got no informations inside my table yet thats why i couldnt test it)

Comment: Some error checking wouldn't hurt.